# MapFrom not working properly in AutoMapper 11.0.1

Tags: automapper, .net-6.0

Upgrading to AutoMapper v11.0.1 from v10.1.1 causes any profiles I have that do a `.ForMember` mapping to ignore those members.  I know the Profile is being read as it maps the rest of the object properly.  The project also coincidentally was upgraded to .Net 6.0 from .Net Core 3.1, but based on my testing and downgrading between various versions, it appears AutoMapper is the culprit.

The profile and objects are as follows:

```cs
// SeminarEventProfile 
public class SeminarEventProfile : Profile
{
    public SeminarEventProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ViewModels.SeminarEvent, UpdateSeminarEvent>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.StartDate,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToDateTime(src.Date + ' ' + src.StartTime))
            )
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.EndDate,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToDateTime(src.Date + ' ' + src.EndTime))
            )
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.AbstractProperty,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Abstract)
            );

    }
}

// relevant fields from ViewModels.SeminarEvent
public class SeminarEvent
{
    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    public string EndTime { get; set; }

    public string Abstract { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

// relevant fields from UpdateSeminarEvent - generated AutoRest model
public partial class UpdateSeminarEvent
{
    public System.DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public string AbstractProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The following is the debugger of the incoming object:

[image: View of a debugger of ViewModels.SeminarEvent data fields]

In AutoMapper v10.1.1, it properly maps the `AbstractProperty`, `EndTime`, and `StartTime`.

[image]

In AutoMapper v11.0.1, all values are null.

[image]

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: I had troubles reproducing the problem in a gist until @Stephan added the comment about constructors/AutoRest.  I had been excluding the generated constructor.  Once I added that, the problem appeared.   [This gist](https://gist.github.com/ewdieckman/c9295b7d81e73b07e1ad6eb6cadf34c8) reproduces the problem.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html

Comment: That is helpful to be able to disable constructor.   By adding `cfg.DisableConstructorMapping();`, it did properly map.   Clearly there must have been a change between AutoMapper 10.1.1 and AutoMapper 11 to prefer constructor mapping over mapping fields.   Thanks, @LucianBargaoanu.

Comment: Actually the old behaviour was a bug and caused mapping to happen twice.

Answer (score 0):

We have the exact same error: AutoMapper's behavior regarding constructors seems to have changed in version 11.

AutoRest generates classes that have the following constructors. As soon as these constrcutors are there (it doesnt matter if the code was generated from AutoRest), the AutoMapper only returns empty objects and ignores the whole configuration for this Type.

```
public ctor(string field1 = null, string field2 = null)
{
   this.Field1 = field1;
   this.Field2 = field2
}
```

Edit:
The mapping only fails with the generic method `_mapper.Map<Type>(source)`. The mapping via `_mapper.Map(source, destination)` works as expected.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html