# AutoMapper v11.0.1 not mapping properties when destination class has constructor with optional parameters

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0

> Note: This post has been greatly simplified following several rounds of investigation to communicate the root problem without being overly-verbose. View the edit history for a full log of the investigation.

---

I'm trying to update AutoMapper in one of my projects from v10.0.0 to v11.0.1.

I find that after updating, there are some properties of my write models that aren't being mapped to the corresponding domain entities.

After investigating this, I've determined that this happens when:

1. A `Parent` class depends on a collection of `Child` objects;
2. The `Child` collection is encapsulated within its own `ChildGroup` class rather than passed directly as an `ICollection<Child>` to `Parent`;
3. The `Parent` class accepts this `ChildGroup` as an *optional* parameter through its constructor: `public Parent(ChildGroup? childGroup = null) { ... }`.

#### SSCCE

Based on a long series of experiments and homing in on the root cause, I've attempted to reproduce this issue with as minimal as code as possible in the SSCCE below.

```
using AutoMapper;

public class Program
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.AddProfile<ExampleProfile>());
        var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        var writeModel = CreateExampleWriteModel();

        var parent = mapper.Map<Parent>(writeModel);

        if (parent.ChildGroup?.Children.Count != 3)
            throw new Exception("ChildGroup property was not mapped");
    }

    private static ParentWriteModel CreateExampleWriteModel()
    {
        var children = new List<ChildWriteModel>
            {
                new()
                {
                    Foo = 1
                },
                new()
                {
                    Foo = 2
                },
                new()
                {
                    Foo = 3
                }
            };

        return new ParentWriteModel
        {
            Children = children
        };
    }
}

#region Mapping Logic

public class ExampleProfile : Profile
{
    public ExampleProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ParentWriteModel, Parent>().ForMember(
            dest => dest.ChildGroup,
            opt => opt.MapFrom((src, _, _, ctx) =>
            {
                // For v11+, this lambda doesn't get called if 'Parent' contains a constructor with optional parameters.
                return new ChildGroup(ctx.Mapper.Map<List<Child>>(src.Children));
            }));

        CreateMap<ChildWriteModel, Child>();
    }
}

#endregion

#region Write Models

public class ParentWriteModel
{
    public ICollection<ChildWriteModel> Children { get; init; }
}

public class ChildWriteModel
{
    public int Foo { get; init; }
}

#endregion

#region Domain

/// <summary>
/// Parents will indirectly own zero to many <c>Child</c> objects through a <c>ChildGroup</c>.
/// </summary>
public class Parent
{
    public Parent(ChildGroup? childGroup = null)
    {
        ChildGroup = childGroup;
    }

    public ChildGroup ChildGroup { get; private init; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Encapsulates a collection of <c>Child</c> objects and potentially exposes methods to perform aggregate operations on them.
/// </summary>
public class ChildGroup
{
    public ChildGroup(ICollection<Child> thresholds)
    {
        Children = thresholds.ToList();
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Child> Children { get; } = null!;
}

/// <summary>
/// A simple class at the bottom of the class composition hierarchy.
/// </summary>
public class Child
{
    public Child(int foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }

    public int Foo { get; private init; }
}

#endregion
```

With AutoMapper v10, this SSCCE works without issue.

After upgrading to v11, I find the `ChildGroup` property is not mapped. This can be traced back to the fact that AutoMapper does not invoke the lambda defined for `CreateMap<ParentWriteModel, Parent>()` (written as a statement lambda for ease of breakpointing).

It is unclear from the [Upgrade Guide](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html) why this version should have changed AutoMapper's behaviour in this regard.

As posted in the answers section, it's possible to work around this by using the non-generic version of `IMapper.Map` that requires a pre-instantiated object, but it's not clear *why* this approach should now need to be adopted when this code worked fine as-is in v10 and nothing in the Upgrade Guide suggests that it should have changed in any way.

**Edit**:

Through a git bisect on AutoMapper, I've narrowed it down to [this commit](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/commit/e12e2367c3b91393add96d0436a5af7b4e56252b) as the one that causes the SSCCE to break.

Specifically, the code that breaks it is the change to `TypeMap.ConstructorParameterMatches`:

```
public bool ConstructorParameterMatches(string destinationPropertyName) =>
-    ConstructorMap?.CtorParams.Any(c => !c.HasDefaultValue && string.Equals(c.Parameter.Name, destinationPropertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) == true;
+    ConstructorMap.CtorParams.Any(c => string.Equals(c.Parameter.Name, destinationPropertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

This changes the assignment function used for `ChildGroup` (constructed in `TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateAssignmentFunc`) from:

```
.Try {
    .Block(
        Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup $resolvedValue,
        Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup $propertyValue) {
        .Block() {
            $resolvedValue = .Invoke (.Constant<AutoMapper.Configuration.MemberConfigurationExpression`3+<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1[Playground.AutomapperIssue.ParentWriteModel,Playground.AutomapperIssue.Parent,Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup,Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup]>(AutoMapper.Configuration.MemberConfigurationExpression`3+<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1[Playground.AutomapperIssue.ParentWriteModel,Playground.AutomapperIssue.Parent,Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup,Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup]).mappingFunction)(
                $src,
                $typeMapDestination,
                $typeMapDestination.ChildGroup,
                $ctxt);
            $propertyValue = .If ($resolvedValue == null) {
                .Default(Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup)
            } .Else {
                $resolvedValue
            };
            $typeMapDestination.ChildGroup = $propertyValue
        }
    }
} .Catch (System.Exception $ex) {
    .Block() {
        .Throw .New AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException(
            "Error mapping types.",
            $ex,
            .Constant<AutoMapper.TypePair>(AutoMapper.TypePair),
            .Constant<AutoMapper.TypeMap>(AutoMapper.TypeMap),
            .Constant<AutoMapper.PropertyMap>(AutoMapper.PropertyMap));
        .Default(Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup)
    }
}
```

To the following:

```
.If ($dest == null) {
    .Default(Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup)
} .Else {
    .Try {
        .Block(
            Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup $resolvedValue,
            Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup $propertyValue) {
            .Block() {
                $resolvedValue = .Invoke (.Constant<AutoMapper.Configuration.MemberConfigurationExpression`3+<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1[Playground.AutomapperIssue.ParentWriteModel,Playground.AutomapperIssue.Parent,Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup,Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup]>(AutoMapper.Configuration.MemberConfigurationExpression`3+<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1[Playground.AutomapperIssue.ParentWriteModel,Playground.AutomapperIssue.Parent,Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup,Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup]).mappingFunction)(
                    $src,
                    $typeMapDestination,
                    $typeMapDestination.ChildGroup,
                    $ctxt);
                $propertyValue = .If ($resolvedValue == null) {
                    .Default(Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup)
                } .Else {
                    $resolvedValue
                };
                $typeMapDestination.ChildGroup = $propertyValue
            }
        }
    } .Catch (System.Exception $ex) {
        .Block() {
            .Throw .New AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException(
                "Error mapping types.",
                $ex,
                .Constant<AutoMapper.TypePair>(AutoMapper.TypePair),
                .Constant<AutoMapper.TypeMap>(AutoMapper.TypeMap),
                .Constant<AutoMapper.PropertyMap>(AutoMapper.PropertyMap));
            .Default(Playground.AutomapperIssue.ChildGroup)
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, it looks like the first assignment function will always try to call the mapping function defined in `ExampleProfile`, but the latter will avoid this if the destination object (`Parent`) is null.

**Edit**

Raised as a [Github Issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/4100).

Comment: Try to simplify your repro. The DI stuff should be irrelevant. `MapPerformanceMetricScoreRule` too. That's your code and has little to do with AM itself.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I kept the DI code in because I think once a solution is found, it would be more helpful to others that are also using AutoMapper within ASP.NET Core. It could be that a solution that works when manually instantiating a `MapperConfiguration` and creating a mapper from it (as in this [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9)) might not work within a project that uses the Microsoft DI container to resolve mappers. I'll try to create a simplified repro without the DI code and irrelevant code and update later on today, though.

Comment: The new repro is missing a constructor, but other than that, it works for me.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Just to clarify, do you mean adding a parameterless constructor for the `Parent` class? This works, but it breaks even with this parameterless constructor if the class has another constructor with optional parameters. I've updated the post to demonstrate this.

Comment: Maybe try to write code that actually works? :) Maybe someone will do it for you, but you could try smth meanwhile. I'm sure that a better understanding of how AM works goes a long way.

Comment: "Maybe try to write code that actually works?"

I'm not sure what's meant by this. The code worked fine with AutoMapper v10, it breaks on upgrading to v11. If it's affecting me, it's also likely to be a problem for many other people when they come around to making the upgrade, so a documented solution would be useful for others as well.

Comment: I don't see any effort to actually understand what's going on. And no, it isn't a problem. People already figured things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the best solution was to shift away from AutoMapper towards an alternative object-mapping library, in our case [Mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster). There are three main reasons for this.

#### Confidence in Library Maintainers

We can't continue to rely on a library that's breaking its functionality in undocumented ways and then trying to pass this off as "by design". It's quite telling that the AutoMapper repo has [zero open issues](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues); any bug reports are immediately converted to discussions and closed, and the corresponding "discussion" hardly lives up to its name as any follow-up questions/requests for clarifications are initially ignored, subsequently deleted, and the thread itself is then locked.

#### Ease of Migration

We were able to migrate our mapping logic from AutoMapper v10 to the latest stable version of Mapster (v7.3.0) without having to rewrite too much of our code.

On the other hand, updating our code to work with AutoMapper v11 might have involved us either rewriting our *domain layer* to accommodate undocumented changes to AutoMapper's mapping behaviour (its sudden inability to map to classes that have constructors with optional parameters under certain scenarios) or to change the way we map between objects in all of our command and query handlers. We know that v12 would have introduced further breaking changes that would have been a challenge for us to work around.

#### Performance Improvements

Some quick benchmarking suggests that Mapster offers us better performance than AutoMapper. Included below are the benchmark results for mapping a complex domain object graph to its corresponding read model using AutoMapper and Mapster with Fast Expression Compiler:

```
MappingBenchmarks.MapWithAutoMapper: DefaultJob
Runtime = .NET 6.0.5 (6.0.522.21309), X64 RyuJIT AVX2; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 10.585 us, StdErr = 0.060 us (0.57%), N = 56, StdDev = 0.449 us
Min = 9.861 us, Q1 = 10.256 us, Median = 10.419 us, Q3 = 10.997 us, Max = 11.585 us
IQR = 0.741 us, LowerFence = 9.143 us, UpperFence = 12.109 us
ConfidenceInterval = [10.376 us; 10.794 us] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.209 us (1.97% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.41, Kurtosis = 1.89, MValue = 2.97
-------------------- Histogram --------------------
[ 9.855 us ; 10.182 us) | @@@@@@@@@
[10.182 us ; 10.674 us) | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[10.674 us ; 10.984 us) | @@@@@@@
[10.984 us ; 11.293 us) | @@@@@@@@@@@@
[11.293 us ; 11.623 us) | @@@
---------------------------------------------------

MappingBenchmarks.MapWithMapster: DefaultJob
Runtime = .NET 6.0.5 (6.0.522.21309), X64 RyuJIT AVX2; GC = Concurrent Workstation
Mean = 8.017 us, StdErr = 0.029 us (0.36%), N = 15, StdDev = 0.112 us
Min = 7.849 us, Q1 = 7.929 us, Median = 7.996 us, Q3 = 8.098 us, Max = 8.275 us
IQR = 0.169 us, LowerFence = 7.676 us, UpperFence = 8.351 us
ConfidenceInterval = [7.898 us; 8.136 us] (CI 99.9%), Margin = 0.119 us (1.49% of Mean)
Skewness = 0.6, Kurtosis = 2.59, MValue = 2
-------------------- Histogram --------------------
[7.790 us ; 8.051 us) | @@@@@@@@@@
[8.051 us ; 8.335 us) | @@@@@
---------------------------------------------------

// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.2, OS=Windows 10 (10.0.19044.2006/21H2/November2021Update)
Intel Core i7-8850H CPU 2.60GHz (Coffee Lake), 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.300
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.5 (6.0.522.21309), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
  DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.5 (6.0.522.21309), X64 RyuJIT AVX2


|            Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |    Median | Ratio | RatioSD |
|------------------ |----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|--------:|
| MapWithAutoMapper | 10.585 us | 0.2088 us | 0.4495 us | 10.419 us |  1.00 |    0.00 |
|    MapWithMapster |  8.017 us | 0.1192 us | 0.1115 us |  7.996 us |  0.73 |    0.03 |
```

Answer (score 1):

The link you mentioned: [MapFrom not working properly in AutoMapper 11.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71387158/mapfrom-not-working-properly-in-automapper-11-0-1), the solution seems to be able to solve the problem.

```
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
var writeModel = CreateExampleWriteModel();
var Parent = new Parent();
//var parent = mapper.Map<Parent>(writeModel);
var parent = mapper.Map(writeModel, Parent);

if (parent.ChildGroup is null)
        throw new Exception("ChildGroup property was not mapped");
```

Test Result:
[image]

Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi Chen, thanks for the response. This is probably a case of me simplifying the SSCCE too far so that the solution that works for it wouldn't be suitable for the real-world case. I ought to have documented earlier why I don't think this approach would work for me, and I've updated my post now with an explanation and an amendment to the SSCCE.